# Printing the return of a function in multiple lines

Tags: c, terminal, printf

I'm learning C and currently doing an exercise where I need to convert a decimal input into binary, I was able to write a function that sucefully converts the decimal inputed into binary but the question asks for the output to be printed one number per line, example, the conversion of "17" is "10001", but the question wants the numbers to be printed one number per line, not in a one row.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int convert(int dec){
    
    if (dec > 0) {
        return (dec % 2 + 10 * convert(dec / 2));
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    int dec;
    
    printf("Type a decimal number: ");
    scanf("%d", &dec);
    
    
    printf("%d\n", convert(dec));
    
    return 0;
}
```

If I input `30` my current output is

```
11110
```

But I want my output to be

```
1
1
1
1
0
```

What should I do?

Comment: You should print each digit as you convert it, not after you have converted the whole number.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting into the binary result into another integer, simply print them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void convert(int dec)
{
    if (dec > 0) {
        convert(dec / 2);
        printf("%d\n", dec % 2);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int dec;

    printf("Type a decimal number: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &dec) == 1) {
        convert(dec);
    }
}
```

This is also safer against integer overflow compared to your orginial implementation.

Note: It's possible that this could result in a stack overflow if the input is a very large number (think of a number with a million digits, for example).
But if you are going to deal with such numbers, you can't use `int` to start with and will have to take a different approach.

Comment: What approach should I take if I want my input (X) to be 0 <= X <= 1.000.000.000?
Just change de int to long?

Comment: You can check the value of `INT_MAX` of your implementation. Typically, `INT_MAX` is 2147483647 on a 32-bit system with sizeof(int) == 4. So it's good enough for the range you mentioned. But you can also use larger integer types such as `unsigned long long` or `uintmax_t` if needed (obviously, check the max values for these types in your implementation).